# CruiseControl.NET stalls with Psexec

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, psexec, ranorex

I have a strange problem using CC.NET with psexec.

I'm essentially duplicating a build server, except for a couple of name changes on each. Both are VMs. The first server works great, but the almost identical project on the second does not complete the CC.NET build. This happens after getting to the part of the CC.NET server configuration that triggers a batch file with a psexec command.

The psexec command is simple and serves to trigger an exe file, which is a Ranorex automated test case. The test case needs to run in the current user's session (session 1) so that the UI components are visable (this is a Ranorex constraint).

This is the command:

```
psexec \\<server name> -i 1 cmd /c C:\Users\build\<path to exe>
```

The OS is Windows 7, Ranorex is 3.1, and CC.NET and Psexec are the latest version as of this date.

The output from the CC.NET build log is as follows (this is just the last part):

```
<buildresults>
  <message level="Error">PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely</message>
  <message level="Error">Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich</message>
  <message level="Error">Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com</message>
</buildresults>
```

This seems to be output from psexec. The only way I can get this log is if I force CC.NET to abort the build at the point is hangs. Anyone have any ideas as to why the build hangs at psexec part?

Comment: Are you running ccnet under the same account on both servers?

Answer (score 1):

PSExec has always had such "hang" issue, one of the solutions being that you have to redirect the output to >nul.

http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-always-hangs-when-run-from-java_topic5013.html

Comment: The build still hangs when it gets to the executable part (ie the psexec command). I changed the command to psexec \\<server> -i 1 >nul cmd /c C:\Users\build\<path to exe> but still the same problem.

Comment: The problem was that psexec was triggered by the CC.NET service. This service was running under session 0, while my account was under session 1. As a result, the dialogue asking me to accept terms when first running psexec was not visible to me. After modifying the service properties to "Allow service to interact with desktop", I was able to switch between sessions, click the agreement, switch back to my session, and have the executable complete.